# Calling AJAX 'consequences' only after file load

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have the following code:

```js
Aventura.prototype.loadMap = function(u,f) {
  var av = this;
  $.getJSON("js/aventura/"+u+"/"+f, (function(data) { av.map = data; }));
};
```

It gets a JSON file `f` in directory `u` and upon loading it sets `window.Aventura.map` as the JSON response. Everything was working fine here *until some code depended on `Aventura.map`*. The problem is I have this init function to set up the object:

```js
Aventura.prototype.init = function(u,f) {
  this.loadMap(u,f);
  this.testRAF();
  this.buildEnv();
  this.generate();
  this.startEventListeners();
  this.resize();
  this.activateWidgets();
};
```

`Aventura.buildEnv` and `Aventura.generate` both need `Aventura.map` to be set. How do I make it so they only execute after `Aventura.loadMap` is done? I still need it all to be asynchronous and I have no clue how to work this out.

Comment: Have loadmap take a callback, place all code below loadmap in a function you call into that callback. use the callback in the success function of the getJSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the initialization of the `Aventura` object depends on data retrieved asynchronously, you have no other choice than deferring the initialization of the `Aventura` object itself after the HTTP request returns.

A possible variant could be putting the result in the very same resource your main script is loaded from, and initializing `av` on DOM loaded:

```
<html>
<head>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <script id="map-data" lang="application/json">
    // json encoded data here
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Note it's the same concept: the object is initialized once you have gathered the needed information.

Comment: Yeah, I ended up putting all the dependent methods as deferred. The only way it seemed to work, so it seems I'll have to break things down a little in my code.